# Using 3D Bezier Curve but having different shading

Tags: 3d-view, bezier-curves

I used 3D Bezier Curve to create a 3D model. However, it kinda has different shades. I don't know what I did wrong. Could anyone please tell me what I did wrong? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: In Edit mode, try to select everything and hit CTRL+N to Make Normals Consistent, also go to Shading/UVs and press Faces: Smooth. And make sure you don't have any vertices doubles (W -> Remove Doubles). Hopefully something of that could do the job :)
If not, upload your .blend via this url and add the link to your post:
http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 2):

Is your curve made from a single continuous segment, or does it have multiple separate segments?

If it has multiple separate segments some of them may have a different direction, yielding inverted normals. You can either:

- Invert the curve direction of the affected segments in *Edit Mode*, by pressing *Switch Direction* button in the tool shelf, or
- Tick the *Calc Order* in the *Screw* modifier to make them consistent automatically

[image]

If you already converted it to a mesh or applied all modifiers just enter edit mode, select all faces and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to recalculate normals.